# ElasticSearch fails to return a result on a keyword field where the value contains an apostrophe

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

The application I am working on allows any character to be used in a tag.  Tags are stored in the document as an array.  Other characters seem to work fine but an apostrophe does not.  In a previous version of ES, we had this field mapped as an analyzed string but the current version does not allow us to use some of the aggregations we were using so I changed it to a keyword and this problem surfaced.  When I query for documents with the specified tag, I get no results even though I know my query is correct for the field(the same query returns results for all other tags except tags containing an apostrophe).  The setup is as follows:

**Field Mapping:**

```
{ 
    "tags" : {
       "type" : "keyword",
       "store" : true
    }
}
```

**Field data:**

```
"tags" : [
    "Mike's Tag"
  ]
```

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "tags:\"Mike's Test\"",
            "default_operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you wan't scoring on tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want scoring on tag you can use `term` query to get the desired result.

Use the query below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tags": "Mike's Tag"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Update after comments**:

In case you want to do it via `query_string` here is the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Mike's Tag",
      "fields": [
        "tags"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: I would still suggest you to use `term` or `terms` query in filter context if you don't want scoring.

Output of above query (using `term` query):

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "tags": [
            "Mike's Tag",
            "Another Tag"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "tags": [
            "Mike's Tag",
            "Another one Tag"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added the output of my query on my sample data and it works fine. I don't see any issue of apostrophe here.

Comment: Can you share one of the complete sample document in your index that should be part of result?

Comment: It worked. I wrote the query incorrectly.  Unfortunately this requires me to rewrite a lot of code.  I was really hoping there was a way to make the query_search work.  But thank you for your help.

Comment: Added the query by using `query_string`

Comment: Interesting, I was under the impression that elasticsearch would interpret the field inline and the field in the fields array the same.